# Load Validation Set into memory

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm trying to train a DenseNet model on a set of patches. My Dataset has 20k images for training and 6k for evaluation.

This is my main function :

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    for epoch in range(START_EPOCH, START_EPOCH+hp.epoch):
        adjust_learning_rate(optimizer,epoch)
        train(epoch, hp.wrong_save)
        #mining(epoch)
        valid(epoch)
```

I adjust the learning rate at each epoch due to learning rate decay, I run my training which loads my `trainloader` to the GPU and then I run a validation function on my validation set to check some metrics at each epoch.

I have a Nvidia GTX1060 (6 GB) and I can load the train set without no problem, but when I load the `valloader`, I get:

```
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 74.12 MiB (GPU 0; 5.93 GiB total capacity; 4.73 GiB already allocated; 75.06 MiB free; 19.57 MiB cached)
```

I would like to know what do you think about the best approach here. Is it possible to load my evaluation set not to the GPU and run the evaluation? Is there any workaround?

There are my train and valid functions:

```
# Optimization, Loss Function Init
criterion = nn.BCELoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=args.lr, momentum=hp.momentum, weight_decay=hp.weight_decay)

def train(epoch, wrong_save=False):
    ''' trian net using patches of slide.
        save csv file that has patch file name predicted incorrectly.

    Args:
        epoch (int): current epoch
        wrong_save (bool):  If True, save the csv file that has patch file name
                            predicted incorrectly
    '''

    print('\nEpoch: %d' % epoch)

    net.train()
    train_loss = 0
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    wrong_list = []

    for batch_idx, (inputs, targets, filename) in enumerate(trainloader):
        if USE_CUDA:
            inputs = inputs.cuda()
            targets = torch.FloatTensor(np.array(targets).astype(float)).cuda()

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        inputs, targets = Variable(inputs), Variable(targets)
        outputs = net(inputs)
        outputs = torch.squeeze(outputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, targets)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        train_loss += loss.item()
        total += targets.size(0)
        batch_size = targets.shape[0]

        outputs += Variable((torch.ones(batch_size) * (THRESHOLD)).cuda())
        outputs = torch.floor(outputs)
        correct += outputs.data.eq(targets.data).cpu().sum()
        filename_list = filename

        if wrong_save == True:
            for idx in range(len(filename_list)):
                if outputs.data[idx] != targets.data[idx]:
                    wrong_name = filename_list[idx]
                    wrong_list.append(wrong_name)

        progress_bar(batch_idx, len(trainloader), 'Loss: %.3f | Acc: %.3f%% (%d/%d)'
            % (train_loss/(batch_idx+1), 100.*correct/total, correct, total))

    if wrong_save == True:
        wrong_csv = open(cf.wrong_path+'wrong_data_epoch'+str(epoch)+'.csv','w',encoding='utf-8')
        wr = csv.writer(wrong_csv)
        for name in wrong_list:
            wr.writerow([name])
        wrong_csv.close()

CUR_TRA_ACC.append(100.*correct/total)

def valid(epoch):
    ''' valid net using patches of slide.
        Save checkpoint if AUC score is higher than saved checkpoint's.

    Args:
        epoch (int): current epoch
    '''

    global BEST_AUC
    global THRESHOLD
    global LR_CHANCE
    global CK_CHANCE
    global LR_DECAY

    net.eval()
    valid_loss = 0
    total = 0
    correct = 0

    outputs_list = np.array([])
    targets_list = np.array([])

    for batch_idx, (inputs, targets) in enumerate(valloader):
        if USE_CUDA:
            inputs = inputs.cuda()
            targets = torch.FloatTensor(np.array(targets).astype(float)).cuda()

        batch_size = targets.shape[0]
        inputs, targets = Variable(inputs, volatile=True), Variable(targets)
        outputs = net(inputs)
        total += targets.size(0)
        outputs = torch.squeeze(outputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, targets)
        valid_loss += loss.item()

        _outputs = np.array(outputs.data.cpu()).astype(float)
        _targets = np.array(targets.data.cpu()).astype(float)
        outputs_list = np.append(outputs_list, _outputs)
        targets_list = np.append(targets_list, _targets)

        outputs += Variable((torch.ones(batch_size) * (1-THRESHOLD)).cuda())
        outputs = torch.floor(outputs)
        correct += int(outputs.eq(targets).cpu().sum())

        progress_bar(batch_idx, len(valloader), 'Loss: %.3f | Acc: %.3f%% (%d/%d)'
                    % (valid_loss/(batch_idx+1), 100.*correct/total, correct, total))

    print(tp, tn, fp, fn)
    correct, tp, tn, fp, fn, recall, precision, specificity, f1_score, auc, threshold = stats(outputs_list, targets_list)
    acc = correct/total
    THRESHOLD = threshold

    print(tp, tn, fp, fn)

    print('Acc: %.3f, Recall: %.3f, Prec: %.3f, Spec: %.3f, F1: %.3f, Thres: %.3f, AUC: %.3f'
        %(acc, recall, precision, specificity, f1_score, threshold, auc))
    print('%17s %12s\n%-11s %-8d    %-8d\n%-11s %-8d    %-8d'
        %('Tumor', 'Normal','pos',tp,fp,'neg',fn,tn))
    print("lr: ",args.lr * (0.5 ** (LR_DECAY)), "lr chance:",LR_CHANCE)

    # plot data
    CUR_EPOCH.append(epoch)
    CUR_VAL_ACC.append(acc)
    CUR_LOSS.append(valid_loss/(batch_idx+1))
    CUR_LR.append(args.lr * (0.5 ** (LR_DECAY)))

    # Save checkpoint.
    if auc > BEST_AUC:
        print('saving...')
        BEST_AUC = auc
        state = {
            'net': net if USE_CUDA else net,
            'acc': acc,
            'loss': valid_loss,
            'recall': recall,
            'specificity': specificity,
            'precision': precision,
            'f1_score': f1_score,
            'auc': auc,
            'epoch': epoch,
            'lr': args.lr * (0.5**(LR_DECAY)),
            'threshold': threshold
        }
        torch.save(state, './checkpoint/ckpt.t7')
```

And this is how I construct my dataset:

```
def get_dataset(train_transform, test_transform, train_max, 
                val_max, subtest_max, ratio=0, mining_mode=False):
    ''' dataset function to get train, valid, subtest, test, mining dataset

    Args:
        train_transform (torchvision.transforms): train set transform for data argumentation
        test_transform (torchvision.transfroms): test set transform for data argumentation
        train_max (int): limit of trian set
        val_max (int): limit of validation set 
        subtest_max (int): limit of subtest set
        ratio (int): for mining_mode, inclusion ratio of train set compared mining set
        mining_mode (bool): If true, return mining dataset  
    '''
    train_dataset = camel(cf.dataset_path + 'train/', usage='train',
                            limit = train_max, transform=train_transform)

    val_dataset = camel(cf.dataset_path + 'validation/', usage='val',
                            limit = val_max, transform=test_transform)

    subtest_dataset = camel(cf.dataset_path + 'test/', usage='subtest', 
                            limit = subtest_max, transform=test_transform)

    test_dataset = camel(cf.test_path, usage ='test',transform=test_transform)

    if mining_mode == True:
        mining_dataset = camel(cf.dataset_path + 'mining/', usage='mining',
                                train_ratio = ratio, transform=train_transform)
        return train_dataset, val_dataset, subtest_dataset, test_dataset, mining_dataset

    else:
        return train_dataset, val_dataset, subtest_dataset, test_dataset
```

Comment: Hi, Have you found the solution? I am facing same problem.